# What should be the regex expresesion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string

I am trying to separate the time from AM in a string.
The code

```
content= "11:20pm"
content = re.findall(r"[^\W\d_]+|\d+", content)
print(content)
```

I expect `['11:20','pm']` but with my code I get `['11','20','pm']`
What should I do?

Comment: Why do you expect that? What part of your regexp matches `:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match the time by adding `(?::\d+)?` pattern to the `\d+` alternative:

```py
content= "11:20pm"
content = re.findall(r"[^\W\d_]+|\d+(?::\d+)?", content)
print(content) # => ['11:20', 'pm']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/nu2xZq) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tgof1C/1).

Note you might want to extend the pattern to also match float values, and if yes, you would need to use `r"[^\W\d_]+|\d+(?:[:.]\d+)?"`.

*Details*:

- `[^\W\d_]+` - one or more letters
- `|` - or
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?::\d+)?` - an  optional sequence of a `:~ and one or more digits.

Answer (score 2):

You can match time with `\d\d:\d\d` or `\d\d?:\d\d` if you need to deal with single digits & then match the am/pm stuff with `\w\w` for text. This makes the regex more readable

```
content= "11:20pm"
content = re.findall(r"\d\d?:\d\d|\w\w", content)
print(content)
```